# Trying to use Entity Framework 7 with Dependency Injection, but getting an error on AddEntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Environment:
VS 2015
frameworks: dnx46
"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddEntityFramework(); // fails with this line
        }
```

> **Error   CS0012**    The type 'IServiceCollection' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

I've already added the assembly reference for "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection".  
Let me know if additional details are needed.

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll is in dnx451 . Your compile error is this ...On the other hand how did you define your DB here ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by replacing the following in the project.json file:

```
 "frameworks": {   "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
       "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-16147"
     }   },   "dnxcore50": { } },
```

by :
(new:)

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```